# Why is GitLab docker-windows executor so slow?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

When I run a completely new git repository, with only `README.md` and `.gitlab-ci.yml` and using the standard `shell` executor in GitLab, the whole job takes 4 seconds. When I do the same using the docker-windows executor, it takes 33 seconds!

My `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
no_git_nor_submodules:
  image: base_on_python36:ltsc2019
  stage: build
  tags:
    - docker-windows
  variables:
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: none
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  script:
    - echo test

no_docker_no_git_nor_submodules:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - normal_runner
  variables:
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: none
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  script:
    - echo test
```

One problem that I thought that it could be is that docker images on Windows tend to be huge. The one I've tested with here is 5.8 GB. When I start a container manually on the server, it just takes a few seconds for it to start. I have also tested with an even larger image, 36 GB, but it also takes around 33 seconds for a job using that image.

As these jobs doesn't do anything and doesn't have any git clone or submodules, what is it that takes time?

I know that GitLab uses a mysterious helper image for cloning the git repository and for other things like that. Could it be this image that makes it super slow to run?

**Update 2019-11-04**

I looked a bit more at this, using `docker events`. It showed that GitLab starts a total of 7 containers, 6 of their own helper image and one of the image that I've defined in `.gitlab-ci.yml`. Each of these docker containers take around 5 seconds to create, run, and destroy, so that explains the time. The only question now is if this is normal behavior for `docker-windows` executor, or if I have something set up the wrong way that makes this super slow.

Comment: Wow, 2 years and zero responses. Did you ever get an answer?

Comment: I opened an issue on GitLab about this and it's just how docker on windows works/worked. I don't think that this has been a focus area for GitLab as I imagine most build jobs are run on Linux anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Docker on Windows has a high overhead when starting new containers and GitLab uses 7 containers per job.

I opened an issue on GitLab [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4842), but I'll post part of my text from there here as well:

---

I looked a bit more at this now, and I think I have figured out at least part of what is going on. There's a command that you can run, docker events. This will print all command that are executed for docker, creating/destroying containers/volumes etc. I ran this command and then started a simple job using the docker-windows executor. The output is like this (cleaned up and filtered a bit):

```
2019-11-04T16:19:02.179255700+01:00 container create image=sha256:6aff8da9cd6b656b0ea3bd4e919c899fb4d62e5e8ac95b876eb4bfd340ed8345, name=runner-Q1iF4bKz-project-305-concurrent-0-predefined-0)
2019-11-04T16:19:07.217784200+01:00 container create image=sha256:6aff8da9cd6b656b0ea3bd4e919c899fb4d62e5e8ac95b876eb4bfd340ed8345, name=runner-Q1iF4bKz-project-305-concurrent-0-predefined-1)
2019-11-04T16:19:13.190800700+01:00 container create image=sha256:6aff8da9cd6b656b0ea3bd4e919c899fb4d62e5e8ac95b876eb4bfd340ed8345, name=runner-Q1iF4bKz-project-305-concurrent-0-predefined-2)
2019-11-04T16:19:18.183059500+01:00 container create image=sha256:6aff8da9cd6b656b0ea3bd4e919c899fb4d62e5e8ac95b876eb4bfd340ed8345, name=runner-Q1iF4bKz-project-305-concurrent-0-predefined-3)
2019-11-04T16:19:23.192798200+01:00 container create image=sha256:b024a0511db77bf777cee287927151584f49a4018798a2bb1aa31332b766cf14, name=runner-Q1iF4bKz-project-305-concurrent-0-build-4)
2019-11-04T16:19:26.221921000+01:00 container create image=sha256:6aff8da9cd6b656b0ea3bd4e919c899fb4d62e5e8ac95b876eb4bfd340ed8345, name=runner-Q1iF4bKz-project-305-concurrent-0-predefined-5)
2019-11-04T16:19:31.239818900+01:00 container create image=sha256:6aff8da9cd6b656b0ea3bd4e919c899fb4d62e5e8ac95b876eb4bfd340ed8345, name=runner-Q1iF4bKz-project-305-concurrent-0-predefined-6)
```

There are 7 containers created in total, 6 of which is the gitlab helper image. Notice how it is around 5 seconds per gitlab image helper created. 6 * 5 seconds = 30 seconds, so about the extra overhead that I've noticed.

---

I also tested the performance again 5 months ago and our shell executor takes 2 seconds to just echo a message. The docker executor takes 21 seconds for the same job. The overhead is less than it was two years ago, but still significant.